# Evaluate $\iint_{D}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}\text{d}x\text d y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate using polar coordinates:$$\iint_{D}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}\text{d}x \, \text d y\qquad D=\bigg\{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leqslant 1\bigg\}$$

**What I did:**

I found that the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) equal to $a\cdot b\cdot r$ I am sure about that and then I tried this:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2} \cdot (abr) \, \text{d} r \, \text d\theta$$ which leads to wrong answer,

a small bird whisper in my ear that I should get this:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1-r^2}abr\right) \, \text{d}r \, \text d\theta$$

I wanted to tell her that I don't understed how to come to this result but she fly away, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change is $x = a r\cos\theta$, $y = b r\sin\theta$:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta = r^2.$$

Comment: You are right, thank you very much @Martin-blas

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution to compute the integral.

The integral represents half of the volume of the ellipsoid 
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+z^2=1
$$
The intersection of this ellipsoid with the plane
$$
z=h
$$
is the ellipse 
$$
\frac{x^2}{(1-h^2)a^2}+\frac{y^2}{(1-h^2)b^2}=1
$$
whose area equals
$$
A(h)=\pi(1-h^2)ab
$$
Therefore the initial integral equals
$$
\int_{h=0}^1 A(h)\;dh = \int_{h=-1}^1 \pi(1-h^2)ab\;dh=\frac{2}{3}\pi ab
$$